# Cant go from one activity to another in Recycler View

Tags: java, android

Hello Every One I am trying to move from one activity to another  using intent in adaptor class of recycler view but I am getting son=me errors in doing so, Following are the errors:
1.PakistaniActivity is not a Enclosing class.
2.Cannot resolve method StatrActivity();

Here is my code:

PakistaniActivity.Java

```
   package com.recycler.hp.navigationbar;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

     public class PakistaniActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pakistani);
    RecyclerView rl=findViewById(R.id.list);
    rl.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    String[] languges={"Badnamiyan", "song2","song3","song4","Song5","song6","song7","song8","song9"};
    rl.setAdapter(new Adaptor(languges));
    }
     }
```

Adaptor.java

```
     package com.recycler.hp.navigationbar;

    import android.content.Intent;
     import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
     import android.view.ViewGroup; 
      import android.widget.Button;
       import android.widget.ImageButton;
     import android.widget.ImageView;
     import android.widget.TextView;
     import android.widget.Toast;

      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.net.URL;



       public class Adaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptor.viewholder> {
private String[] data;

public Adaptor(String[] data) {
    this.data = data;
}


@Override
public viewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item1, parent, false);
    return new viewholder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(viewholder holder, final int position) {
    String title = data[position];
    holder.t.setText(title);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             long x;
             x=getItemId(position);
            if(x==0)
            {
                 Intent intent=new Intent(PakistaniActivity.this,Revival_Activity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.length;
}

public class viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView i;
    TextView t;

    public viewholder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        i = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
        t = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main1);
    }
}

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not starting activities inside the adapter. You can use this adapter:

```
public abstract class ClickableAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {

    private ClickItemListener clickItemListener;

    public void setClickItemListener(ClickItemListener clickItemListener) {
        this.clickItemListener = clickItemListener;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final VH holder, int position) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clickItemListener != null)
                    clickItemListener.onClickItem(holder.itemView, holder.getAdapterPosition());
                else
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Click listener not set");
            }
        });
    }

    public interface ClickItemListener {
        void onClickItem(View v, int position);
    }
}
```

Then make your adapter extend mine:

```
public class Adaptor extends ClickableAdapter<Adaptor.viewholder> {
private String[] data;

public Adaptor(String[] data) {
    this.data = data;
}


@Override
public viewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item1, parent, false);
    return new viewholder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(viewholder holder, final int position) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder,position);
    String title = data[position];
    holder.t.setText(title);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.length;
}

public class viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView i;
    TextView t;

    public viewholder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        i = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
        t = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main1);
    }
}

   }
```

Finally in your activity you can set the behaviour for the adapter:

```
Adaptor adapter = new Adaptor(languges)
rl.setAdapter(adapter);

adapter.setClickItemListener(new ClickableAdapter.ClickItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClickItem(View v, int position) {
                if(position==0)
            {
                 Intent intent=new Intent(PakistaniActivity.this,Revival_Activity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
            }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you kindly tell me what is the need of abstract class,Your code is running fine but I am having understanding it, can you explain what changes did you make and why. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain, the abstract class is the way I found to keep the adding of click listeners abstracted and to make it easier like it used to be in listview. With recycler views it's up to us (the developer) to implement how the list reacts to item clicks. I developed the extension to the original adapter. It simply adds a click listener to each item in the list (view holder).

Comment: Then youcan provide the implementation of the click listener in the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),Revival_Activity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
```

instead of this

```
  Intent intent=new Intent(PakistaniActivity.this,Revival_Activity.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
```

or

pass the context from the from `PakistaniActivity` to the Adapter class and user the context as the data member of the adapter class

Answer (score 0):

Pass the context of PakistaniActivity into Adapter

```
new Adaptor(languges,getApplicationContext);

private Context context;
public Adaptor(String[] data,Conetext context) {
this.data = data; 
this.context = conetext;
}

Intent intent=new Intent(context,Revival_Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The data is peresent in the recycler view I want when user Touch the first item in the list it should move to the new activity (Reviva_Activity)but nothing is happening can you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {          
long x;
x=getItemId(position);
if(x==0){
Intent intent =  new Intent(getContext(), Revival_Activity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```