# RecyclerView - Get the selected position and pass the position to another activity where the same list will appear with that specific item selected

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I have declared a `ViewModel.class` for the RecyclerView an Adapter and I have parsed to the `MainActivity` and to another `Activity` so I have the same adapter for both activities.

I can show the parsed data in both activities but the problem it is I cannot take the data of the selected item to `MainActivity` and then to set to that btnSearch for a click so then I can share between activities the data from the selected item.

Every time when the app is open the first item is selected. What I am trying to achieve is.

1. Get the item position to the MainActivity so when I click for a button search the data of the selectedItem will going to `intent.putExtra` and then get the data at another Activity.
2. If I click the second item and go to another Activity the same item will be selected.

Here is what I have tried so far.

The `SearchEngineAdapter.class`

```
public class SearchEngineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchEngineAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private int selectedItem = 0;
    private static RecyclerViewClickListener itemListener;

    private Context context;
    ArrayList<SearchEngine> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SearchEngineAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchEngine> arrayList, int selectedItem) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int i) {
        holder.tvIcon.setImageResource(arrayList.get(i).getIcon());
        holder.tvId.setText(arrayList.get(i).getId());
        holder.tvSearchUrl.setText(arrayList.get(i).getUrl());
        final String url = holder.tvSearchUrl.getText().toString();

        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("SavedSelected", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putInt("selected", selectedItem);
        editor.apply();

        sp = context.getSharedPreferences("SavedSelected", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int myIntValue = sp.getInt("selected", -1);
        Log.d("Selected", "SharedPreferences" + myIntValue);

        if (selectedItem == i) {
            holder.tvIcon.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#30000000"));
            Intent intent = new Intent("search_engines");
            intent.putExtra("url", url);
            intent.putExtra("selected", selectedItem);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
        } else {
            holder.tvIcon.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
        }

        holder.tvIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("search_engines");
                intent.putExtra("url", url);
                int PreviousSelectedItem = selectedItem;
                selectedItem = i;
                intent.putExtra("selected", selectedItem);
                holder.tvIcon.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#30000000"));
                notifyItemChanged(PreviousSelectedItem);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    // ... Other necessary functions.
}
```

Now the `MainActivity.class`

```
RecyclerView paramRecyclerView;
SearchEngineAdapter sEngineAdapter;

paramRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.lvEngines);
paramRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
paramRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
Intent intent = getIntent();
int intValue = intent.getIntExtra("selected", 0);
sEngineAdapter = new SearchEngineAdapter(context, arrayList, intValue);
paramRecyclerView.setAdapter(sEngineAdapter);

// Calling network APIs to populate the arrayList.
```

The `onResume` function of the `MainActivity` looks like the following.

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    searchPlugin.setText("");
    getChangeColor();
}
```

This is the click handler defined in `MainActivity` which send me to another Activity.

```
btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String newEntry = searchPlugin.getText().toString();
        AddHistory(newEntry);
        getFragmentRefreshListener().onRefresh();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivitySearchEngine.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", url );
        intent.putExtra("name", newEntry);
        intent.putExtra("selected", selectedItem2);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

And the other activity which is `ActivitySearchEngine.class`

```
public class ActivitySearchEngine extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    public String selectedName;
    public int selectedID;
    public String selectedSearchUrl;
    RecyclerView mListView;
    RecyclerView paramRecyclerView;
    SearchEngineAdapter sEngineAdapter;

    ArrayList<SearchEngine> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    final Context context = this;
    int selectedItem;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);

        // Variables initialization

        // Setting up adapter
        paramRecyclerView.setAdapter(sEngineAdapter);
        sEngineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Calling network APIs to populate the arrayList here

        Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
        selectedName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("name");
        selectedID = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("id", 1); //NOTE: -1 is just the default value
        selectedSearchUrl = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("url");

        // Loading the url in a WebView for searching
    }
}
```

I could share the selected item position between these two activities. However, I am not sure how to achieve the behavior of the item is being selected in the `RecyclerView` of the second activity as well. If I select another item in the `RecyclerView` of the second activity, the change should be reflected in the first (i.e. `MainActivity`) as well when I get back to it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? Please specify clearly that what you have achieved and what is the problem now. Thanks.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I have achieved to show the recyclerviewlist in both activites but I want to get the selecteditem to MainActivity at btnSearch and then to share between  mainactivity and another activity.

Comment: Please check the answer and let me know if that solves your problem. Thanks.

Comment: I have modified the question as well. Please edit and modify again if the problem is not the same. Thank you.

Comment: @ReazMurshed you have modified the question as well I have thought.

Comment: Yes, I have. Please feel free to modify your question again using the `edit` option, if that does not describe your problem properly.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I have added another question can you take a look.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536787/how-to-get-the-favicon-from-url-even-the-mobile-does-not-have-any-internet-or-if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a lot of changes in the question and hence the last update of this answer below is the final version.

As far as I could understand about the problem, I can see you are very close to the solution if I had understood correctly. The `SearchEngineAdapter` already has a `selectedItem` variable in it which can be used for highlighting the item selected in `ActivitySearchEngine` as well. You just have to modify the adapter a little bit like the following. I am rewriting the adapter here.

```
public class SearchEngineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchEngineAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private int selectedItem = 0;
    private static RecyclerViewClickListener itemListener;

    private Context context;
    ArrayList<SearchEngine> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Added another argument to be passed in the constructor
    public SearchEngineAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchEngine> arrayList, int selectedItem) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SearchEngineAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.s_engine_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int i) {
        if (selectedItem == i) {
            holder.tvIcon.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#30000000"));
        } else {
            holder.tvIcon.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
        }

        holder.tvIcon.setImageResource(arrayList.get(i).getIcon());
        holder.tvId.setText(arrayList.get(i).getId());
        holder.tvSearchUrl.setText(arrayList.get(i).getUrl());

        holder.tvIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int PreviousSelectedItem = selectedItem;
                selectedItem = i;
                holder.tvIcon.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#30000000"));
                notifyItemChanged(PreviousSelectedItem);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tvId, tvSearchUrl;
        ImageView tvIcon;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivEngineText);
            tvIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivEngine);
            tvSearchUrl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivSearchUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Check that, I just have modified the constructor of your adapter, taking another extra variable which is `selectedItem`. Just pass the selected item position when you are initializing the adapter in both activities. In the default case, you can pass -1, I think you get the idea.

You have passed the selected item position to the `ActivitySearchEngine` as well. Which can be used for initializing for the desired behavior. Hope that helps!

**Update 1:**

I would like to suggest you put the following code to your `onResume` function in the `ActivitySearchEngine` class. You might consider removing the lines from the `onCreate` function of your code as well.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
    selectedName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("name");
    selectedID = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("id", 1); // NOTE: -1 is just the default value
    selectedSearchUrl = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("url");

    sEngineAdapter = new SearchEngineAdapter(context, arrayList, selectedID);
    paramRecyclerView.setAdapter(sEngineAdapter);
}
```

**Update 2:**

The `RecyclerView` in your `MainActivity` is getting reloaded as you are setting the adapter again to the `RecyclerView` in the `onResume` function. Moreover, you are trying to get data from intent which is not available here I think because you have not set any data to be sent to the `MainActivity` when you return back from the `ActivitySearchEngine`. Hence, the `RecyclerView` is reloading again with a fresh set of data.

You might remove the code associated with your `RecyclerView` from the `onResume` function of the `MainActivity` to remove this complication as I think this is not necessary. So the updated `onResume` function will look like the following.

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    searchPlugin.setText("");
    getChangeColor();
}
```

**Update 3:**

Take a `public static` variable in your `MainAcitivity` and declare it as a global variable like the following.

```
// Setting 0 as you wanted to put the first item at the first time
// If you do not want that, then initialize with -1
public static int selectedItem = 0;
```

Now inside your `onCreate` function, remove the lines for getting the `intent`.

```
paramRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.lvEngines);
paramRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
paramRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

// Remove the following
// Intent intent = getIntent();
// int intValue = intent.getIntExtra("selected", 0);

// Move the adapter setup to the onResume
// sEngineAdapter = new SearchEngineAdapter(context, arrayList, selectedItem);
// paramRecyclerView.setAdapter(sEngineAdapter);

// Calling network APIs to populate the arrayList.
```

Modify the `onResume` function in the `MainActivity` to set up the adapter there.

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    searchPlugin.setText("");
    getChangeColor();

    // Set the adapter here 
    sEngineAdapter = new SearchEngineAdapter(context, arrayList, selectedItem);
    paramRecyclerView.setAdapter(sEngineAdapter);
}
```

Modify the `onClickListener` in your adapter like the following. Just add a new line there.

```
holder.tvIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("search_engines");
        intent.putExtra("url", url);
        int PreviousSelectedItem = selectedItem;
        selectedItem = i;

        // Set the static value in the MainActivity 
        // This can be accessed from all other classes
        MainActivity.selectedItem = i;

        intent.putExtra("selected", selectedItem);
        holder.tvIcon.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#30000000"));
        notifyItemChanged(PreviousSelectedItem);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: How do I get the selecteditem to another activites I have writed something like this but if I click the second item and from mainactivity to go in another activity this stays again the first item as clicked ?

`sEngineAdapter = new SearchEngineAdapter(context, arrayList, 0);`

Comment: For example the first item it is automatically selected, I select then the second item and click for going to another activity which is `ActivtiySearchEngine` then there it is again the first item selected not the second and when I click for return back at main activity at the MainActivity it is the the second selected.

Comment: I was able to do that but only now I have the problem it is only when I resume from `ActivitySearchEngine` to `MainActivity` it is not getting the selectedItem at `ActivitySearchEngine`

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check if that helps.

Comment: It helps me but the problem it is when I resume `MainActivity` from `ActivitySearchEngine` it doesnt take the right selectedItem which I have selected to the `ActivitySearchEngine` it takes always the first item.

Comment: Do you have any `onResume` function in your `MainActivity`? If yes, can you please share the code and update your question?

Comment: Yes I have a `onResume` function, I will update now the question.

Comment: Just put the `onResume` function in your `MainActivity.class` and comment here. I will take a look there.

Comment: I have just updated and I have another little question do you know how to save the selected item at shared preferences so everytime I will open the app will tell me the selectedItem not the first selecteditem ?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Let me know if that helps! Please note that I have removed un-necessary code blocks from the question so that it appears to be clean and subjected to the problem only.

Comment: it is not working still the same I will update the code what I have writed for the moment to `MainActivity` and as you can see I have changed the click at the adapter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187897/discussion-between-reaz-murshed-and-spritzig).