# Unable to get favicon from url when mobile does not have any internet or is it possible to save at internal storage and then to read from there

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, xml-parsing

1. I have a parsed `XML` which I have read data from there. I have manually declared some data and the other data will be saved by the user.
2. I have declared with glide but it is not getting the right icon or when there is no internet the icons are hidden.
3. The declared the xml they have the icons at the drawable and when I parse they are readable and I can show.

What I want is there any option to take the favicon and save to drawable or to an internal storage or cache so I can read even if I dont have internet.
The items which are declared manually and parsed for them take the icon from drawable but for the others take the favicon from url.

Here is what I have tried so far.

The `Pojo.class`

```
public class Bookmark implements Parcelable, Comparable  {
    String name, id, nativeUrl, searchUrl;
    long db_id;
    int icon;
    int viewType;

    // Constructor, getters, setters & other default functions are omitted for simplicity.
}
```

The `Adapter.class`

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList;
    BookmarkDB bookmarkDB;
    public static final int ITEM_TYPE_ONE = 0;
    public static final int ITEM_TYPE_TWO = 1;
    boolean connected = false;
    String BASE_URL = "https://besticon-demo.herokuapp.com/icon?url=";
    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    private boolean switchOnOff;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = null;
        if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_ONE) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_TWO) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.add_bookmark, parent, false);
            return new ButtonViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            return  null;
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final int itemType = getItemViewType(position);
        if (itemType == ITEM_TYPE_ONE) {
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.tvName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
            RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
            bookmarkDB = new BookmarkDB(context);
                viewHolder.tvIcon.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getIcon());         

            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(BASE_URL+arrayList.get(position).getSearchUrl() + "&size=32;")
                    .apply(requestOptions)
                    .into(viewHolder.tvIcon);

            viewHolder.tvIcon.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getIcon());
            viewHolder.tvId.setText(arrayList.get(position).getId());
            viewHolder.tvSearchUrl.setText(arrayList.get(position).getSearchUrl()); 
        } else if (itemType == ITEM_TYPE_TWO) {
            ButtonViewHolder buttonViewHolder = (ButtonViewHolder) holder;
            buttonViewHolder.imgButton.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getIcon());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Based on you list you will return the ViewType 
        if (arrayList.get(position).getViewType() == 0) return ITEM_TYPE_ONE;
        else return ITEM_TYPE_TWO;
    }
}
```

Ass you can see at the `Adapter.class`

```
// This get the icon from drawable and it sets to parsed array.
viewHolder.tvIcon.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getIcon());

// This gets the icon from URL and sets it to the parsed array but only when the user has internet.
Glide.with(context)
    .load(BASE_URL+arrayList.get(position).getSearchUrl() + &size=32;")
    .apply(requestOptions)
    .into(viewHolder.tvIcon);
```

This is the declared `XML` which I have parsed, the file it is declared under `res/xml/bookmarks.xml`

```
<Bookmarks>
    <Bookmark name="Bing" hidden="" icon="bing" id="0" nativeUrl="" searchUrl="https://www.bing.com" />
    <Bookmark name="Google"  hidden="" icon="google" id="1" nativeUrl="" searchUrl="https://www.google.com" />
    <Bookmark name="Youtube" hidden="" icon="youtube" id="2" nativeUrl="" searchUrl="http://m.youtube.com" />
</Bookmarks>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I have understood correctly, you have two problems.

1. The default icon is not showing (i.e. hidden) when there is no internet.
2. You want to show the images once loaded even if there is no internet.

Both of these two can be achieved using Glide with minimal change in your code. Just change the image loading portion of your code using Glide like the following.

```
String imageUrl = BASE_URL + arrayList.get(position).getSearchUrl() + "&size=32";
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) 
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .into(viewHolder.tvIcon);
```

`DiskCacheStrategy.ALL` manages the caching of your images and should load the images even if the device is offline. Setting the placeholder using the `.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)` can be used, when the images are not loaded for internet problem and hence you want to show a default image instead.

If you want to read more about the caching strategies, [this link](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html) can help as well.

**Update 1**

Based on your comment, I think you should have an `if` statement here. When the drawable is available locally, then you will use the `setImageResource` function, `else` use Glide to load the image.

**Update 2**

You do not have to save the images locally if you are using Glide with `DiskStrategy.ALL`. It will cache the images and will show automatically when the internet connection is not available. I would like to suggest you to remove the manual setup.

**Update 3**

If you want to use some of the icons from your own drawable, then you might consider putting something like this.

```
if (theIconIsAvailableInDrawable) showThatFromDrawable();
else useGlideToShowTheIconFromUrlUsingDiskCacheStrategy();
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: It is coming the error `Cannot resovle discCacheStrategu` and there in the link that you have attached there is GlideApp if I write the same it send `Cannot resolve symbol GlideApp`
How it is possible the manually data take the icon from there only new entries take from glide because if I let both of them declared it takes as first the glide.

Comment: I was ble to write something like this and it is working but the problem it is the declared manually it is replacing with the glide, I want the manually declared take icons from drawable and only the new saved data take from glide.

`Glide.with(context)
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .apply(requestOptions
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.default_favicon)
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .fitCenter())
                    .into(viewHolder.tvIcon);`

Comment: How do I need to write the `if` statement to check if drawable is available locally ?

Comment: I did not quite understand the problem you have specified. However, please see the update again and let me know if that helps!

Comment: I totally agree with you but that link for fetching icons it is not getting the right icons sometimes.

Comment: Then you should fix the provider which is responsible for sending the links of the images.

Comment: Do you have any link which takes the favicon with 32x32 size or something like this.

Comment: Its possible to save the icons into drawable and then read all of them from drawable, because the manual setup it is something that I have some icons which are designed better from the one which is taking from url.

Comment: I am getting the idea but I need to do more can you explain how to do that?

Comment: I think the question that you are asking should be a separate question. Because you cannot ask several questions in a single post which might confuse the other people when they will come here to look for a specific answer. If you find your question answered, please mark the answer as correct and consider opening another question if necessary. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thank you for your time and your answer, do you mind if you provide in comment a question for me and I will make then a new question ?

Comment: You are most welcome. As far as I have understood, you need to download image while showing it in a `RecyclerView` and you want to use them later. You want to show some images from your drawable folder as well when a better version already exists. You need to post the logic behind selecting the images downloaded from url and stored in your drawable.

Comment: This is what I am looking for

Comment: If you have time please check the new answer or you can edit the question if you need to?

Comment: can you check a new question about `recyclerview` which I have asked ?

Comment: Hey @Spritzig, yes, of course, I can. I am not available until tomorrow. Hope you don't mind. I will take a look at your question. :)

Comment: No problem, I am trying to solve that if not then tomorrow your answer it will be welcomed.

Comment: did you check it ?