# Kotlin Generics for RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: java, android, generics, kotlin

I am trying to write a generic recyclerview adapter. I found a few examples. However, still could not figure out how to achieve a generic adapter. The code I have written is,

```
open abstract class BaseAdapter<T : RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(private val onClickListener: View.OnClickListener, @LayoutRes private val layoutResource:Int) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<T>() {
        var items: MutableList<Item> = mutableListOf()

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): T  {
            val layout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layoutResource, parent, false)
            layout.setOnClickListener(onClickListener)
            return T(layout)
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return items.size
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error at line `return T(layout)`. The error is `Expression 'T' of type 'Int' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found`.

Comment: https://medium.com/@zareahmer89/generic-adapter-using-kotlin-6aa3e57207

Answer (score 5):

I use something like this for a generic this for ListAdapter (making use of [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding))

```kotlin
class BaseListAdapter<T>(
    private val inflate: (layoutInflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup?, attachToParent: Boolean) -> ViewBinding,
    private val bind: (item: T, binding: ViewBinding) -> Unit,
    private val onClick: (item: T) -> Unit,
    compareItems: (old: T, new: T) -> Boolean,
    compareContents: (old: T, new: T) -> Boolean
) : ListAdapter<T, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(DiffCallback(compareItems, compareContents)) {
    var items = emptyList<T>()
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        ItemViewHolder(inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        bind(getItem(position), (holder as BaseListAdapter<T>.ItemViewHolder).binding)
    }

    internal fun setItems(items: List<T>) {
        this.items = items
        this.submitList(items)
    }

    inner class ItemViewHolder(val binding: ViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder((binding).root) {
        init {
            binding.root.setOnClickListener { onClick(getItem(adapterPosition)) }
        }
    }

    private class DiffCallback<K>(
        private val compareItems: (old: K, new: K) -> Boolean,
        private val compareContents: (old: K, new: K) -> Boolean
    ) : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<K>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(old: K, new: K) = compareItems(old, new)
        override fun areContentsTheSame(old: K, new: K) = compareContents(old, new)
    }
}
```

then in the Fragment/Activity you can initiate it like this (for `Customer` and `RvCustomerBinding` as ViewBinding)

```kotlin
val adapter = BaseListAdapter<Customer>(
    { li, parent, attach -> RvCustomerBinding.inflate(li, parent, attach) },
    { item, vb -> (vb as RvCustomerBinding).tvName.text = item.name },
    { item -> displayToast(requireContext(), "Customer: ${item.name}") },
    { old, new -> old.id == new.id },
    { old, new -> old == new }
)
```

Comment: I thought of a similar solution but we can decrease more params here

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin doesn't allow creating object of type that was identified in type parameters (unlike C# can).

So in your case you can leave abstract class without `onCreateViewHolder` method realization. Or you can add another abstract method and call it in `onCreateViewHolder`.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): T  {
    val layout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layoutResource, parent, false)
    layout.setOnClickListener(onClickListener)
    return createHolderInstance(layout)
}

abstract fun createHolderInstance(layout: View): T
```

In this way there should be less code in child classes. For example:

```
class UsersAdapter(...) : BaseAdapter<UserHolder>(...) {
    override fun createHolderInstance(layout: View) = UserHolder(layout)
}
```

Comment: Another option is to add a `(View) -> T` parameter to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In case any one interested for recyclerview adapter

```
abstract class BaseAdapter<T> : RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseAdapter<T>.BaseViewHolder>() {
    protected val models = mutableListOf<T>()

    fun updateData(list: List<T>) {
        models.clear()
        models.addAll(list)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(models[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = models.size

    abstract inner class BaseViewHolder constructor(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        abstract fun bind(model: T)
    }
}
```