# Generic RecyclerView Adapter with ViewBinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-listadapter

I'm attempting to implement a generic RV Adapter, mostly inspired by [THIS COMMENT](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/qy2vg2/does_anyone_else_hate_recyclerviews_and_how/hldl0qi/):

The code:

```
class RVAdapter <T: Any, VB: ViewBinding>(
  private var dataSet: List<T>,
  private val bindingInterface: RVBinding<T, VB>
  ) : ListAdapter<T, RVAdapter<T, VB>.RVHolder>(DiffCallback<T>()) {

  inner class RVHolder(private val binding: ViewBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun<T: Any, VB: ViewBinding> bind(item: T, bindingInterface: RVBinding<T, VB>) {
      bindingInterface.bind(item, (binding as VB)) //3: unchecked cast
    }
  }


  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RVHolder {
    val binding = (VB as ViewBinding).inflate() //1: how do you inflate from generic VB?

    return RVHolder(binding)
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RVHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(getItem(position), bindingInterface)
  }

  override fun getItemCount() = dataSet.size
}


private class DiffCallback<T: Any>: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<T>() {
  //2: how do you implement the following two methods?

  override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: T, newItem: T): Boolean {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
  }

  override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: T, newItem: T): Boolean {
    return oldItem == newItem
  }
}


interface RVBinding<T: Any, VB: ViewBinding> {
  fun bind(item: T, binding: VB)
}
```

I'm facing two main problems:

1. how do I inflate the binding in `onCreateViewHolder()`? Normally, I use `SpecificBinding.inflate()` but that doesn't seem to work with a generic view binding.
2. how would I implement the `DiffUtil` portion in a generic way? Sure, I could compare `old.toString == new.toString` but that's not generic. Also `oldItem == newItem` doesn't have `equals()` implemented.

So how would I solve these problems in a way to make the Adapter as generic as possible? And any other suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: FWIW, this is a very opinionated comment. "I'd probably say that if you've got more than one Adapter for the entire app you're doing it wrong for whatever reason." There's nothing wrong with having simple short adapters. RecyclerView already has a generic adapter. It's called `ListView<T, K>`. Extend that, customize with your types and provide your DiffUtil and you're set.

Comment: Check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56535925/kotlin-generics-for-recyclerview-adapter/64071099#64071099), essentially you can pass the inflating and DiffUtil functions as constructor arguments

Answer (score 2):

For example, you can use the generic structure below.

```
abstract class AbstractViewBindingAdapter<T, VH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder, VB : ViewBinding>(
        private val viewHolder: (binding: VB) -> VH,
        private val bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Boolean) -> VB,
        areItemsTheSameCallback: (old: T, new: T) -> Boolean? = { _, _ -> null },
        areContentsTheSameCallback: (old: T, new: T) -> Boolean? = { _, _ -> null },
        private val onCreateBinding: (holder: VH) -> Unit = {}

) :
        ListAdapter<T, VH>(GenericDiffUtil(areItemsTheSameCallback, areContentsTheSameCallback)) {
    abstract fun bindItems(item: T, holder: VH, position: Int, itemCount: Int)

    var forItemClickListener: ((position: Int, item: T, view: View) -> Unit)? = null
    var onLongClickListener: ((position: Int, item: T, view: View) -> Unit)? = null

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VH, position: Int) {
        val item: T = getItem(holder.bindingAdapterPosition)
        bindItems(item, holder, position, itemCount)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VH {
        val binding = bindingInflater.invoke(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        val holder = setViewHolder(binding)
        onCreateBinding(holder)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListenerCooldown {
            if (holder.bindingAdapterPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                forItemClickListener?.invoke(holder.bindingAdapterPosition, getItem(holder.bindingAdapterPosition), it)
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
            if (holder.bindingAdapterPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                onLongClickListener?.invoke(holder.bindingAdapterPosition, getItem(holder.bindingAdapterPosition), it)
            true
        }
        return holder
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    private fun setViewHolder(binding: ViewBinding): VH = viewHolder(binding as VB)
}
```

GenericDiffUtil.kt

```
class GenericDiffUtil<T>(private val areItemsTheSameCallback: (old: T, new: T) -> Boolean?,
                         private val areContentsTheSameCallback: (old: T, new: T) -> Boolean?) : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<T>() {

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: T, newItem: T): Boolean = areItemsTheSameCallback(oldItem, newItem) ?: newItem == oldItem

    @SuppressLint("DiffUtilEquals")
    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: T, newItem: T): Boolean = areContentsTheSameCallback(oldItem, newItem) ?: newItem == oldItem

}

fun <T> diffUtilDSL(areItemsTheSameCallback: (old: T, new: T) -> Boolean? = { _, _ -> null },
                    areContentsTheSameCallback: (old: T, new: T) -> Boolean? = { _, _ -> null }) = GenericDiffUtil(areItemsTheSameCallback, areContentsTheSameCallback)
```