# How can I dissmiss bottomSheetFragment in Fragment class?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-tools

This is my BottomsheetFragment Showing method. When I user `new BottomSheetFragment().dismiss();`
then shut down apps.

```
 new BottomSheetFragment().
                            show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
                                    new BottomSheetFragment().getTag());
```

This code properly shows bottom sheet Dialog. But I can't user `dismiss();` What is the solution to these issues? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that instead of BottomSheetFragment object your are using BottomSheetFragment class to call dismiss. Please have a look on the code below

```
BottomSheetFragment mBottomSheetFragment = new BottomSheetFragment().
                                show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
                                        new BottomSheetFragment().getTag());
    
    mBottomSheetFragment.dismiss();
```

Comment: I want to dismiss on adapterClass . When calling new BottomSheetFragment().dismiss(); then stop apps... :(

Comment: you have to use interface so you can call your clickListener of adapter class to the Activity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969278/recyclerview-onclicklistener-using-interface/49969478#49969478 as mentioned here