# Hot switch to a viewpager page when a recyclerview item is clicked?

Tags: android

I want to know how to switch to the current item of viewpager when a recyclerview item clicked

when clicking on a recyclerview item it will return the position of the clicked item easily.
a toast message confirms this.

but when I use `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);` it returns null , I can confirm that viewpager has been initialized successfully because it is working well in `onCreate` of my activity.

here is the adapter of the recyclerview

```
    // ViewHolder adapter for RecyclerView
        public class PlanetViewHolder
                extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
                implements View.OnClickListener {
            public PlanetViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);
                v.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getPosition();
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);    
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You have clicked " + ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
    
            }
        }
```

here is the onCreate

```
public class TvShowEpisodeDetails extends MizActivity {

    private static final String SHOW_ID = "showId";

    private ArrayList<TvShowEpisode> mEpisodes = new ArrayList<TvShowEpisode>();
    private int mSeason, mEpisode;
    private String mShowId, mShowTitle;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes mDatabaseHelper;
    private Bus mBus;

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.viewpager_with_toolbar_overlay;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBus = MizuuApplication.getBus();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set theme
        setTheme(R.style.Mizuu_Theme_NoBackground);

        ViewUtils.setupWindowFlagsForStatusbarOverlay(getWindow(), true);

        ViewUtils.setProperToolbarSize(this, mToolbar);

        mShowId = getIntent().getExtras().getString(SHOW_ID);
        mSeason = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("season");
        mEpisode = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("episode");

        mDatabaseHelper = MizuuApplication.getTvEpisodeDbAdapter();

        Cursor cursor = mDatabaseHelper.getEpisodes(mShowId);
        try {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                mEpisodes.add(new TvShowEpisode(this, mShowId,
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_TITLE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_PLOT)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_SEASON)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_AIRDATE)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_DIRECTOR)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_WRITER)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_GUESTSTARS)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_EPISODE_RATING)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_HAS_WATCHED)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapterTvShowEpisodes.KEY_FAVOURITE))
                        ));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

        mShowTitle = MizuuApplication.getTvDbAdapter().getShowTitle(mShowId);
        setTitle(mShowTitle);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.awesomepager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new TvShowEpisodeDetailsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                ViewUtils.updateToolbarBackground(TvShowEpisodeDetails.this, mToolbar, 0, mEpisodes.get(position).getTitle(), Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < mEpisodes.size(); i++) {
                if (mEpisodes.get(i).getSeason().equals(MizLib.addIndexZero(mSeason)) && mEpisodes.get(i).getEpisode().equals(MizLib.addIndexZero(mEpisode))) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    // ViewHolder adapter for RecyclerView
    public class PlanetViewHolder
            extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener {
        public PlanetViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getPosition();
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

            //mViewPager.setAdapter(new TvShowEpisodeDetailsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
            //mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You have clicked " + ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    }
rest of the code
}
```

Comment: hey cyberpunk, can I see how I you instantiated the recycervlew adapter? It could be timing issues.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going crazy here with , here is the  [crash log](https://pastebin.com/QD7AaXLQ)

Comment: I don't know what should I do next

Comment: Sure, I have updated my answer. It will solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your stacktraces, I can conclude that the way you handle UI elements are in the wrong order, meaning lifecycle is ignored.

You should NOT invoke UI elements in your activity from your viewHolder, as viewHolders are "part" of Recyercycleview which is not aware of the activity lifecycle.

A common pattern to invoke UI elements in your activity from your viewHolder is:

```
            Listener
Activity <-----------> RecyclerView_Adapter
```

Well, since you have a listener already, your have a good start.

Just move your `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);` from `viewHolder` to inside the overriden `onClick` Method in Activity through the listener you have.

Let me know if you have more questions, you are almost there!

**EDIT**

If your viewpager is in a fragment, then you should add `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);` to the overriden `onClick` Method in fragment. Simply means that you should invoke `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);` directly from your fragment and use the Adapter Listener just to get the correct time to invoke `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);`.

What is an [Adapter Listener](https://medium.com/android-gate/recyclerview-item-click-listener-the-right-way-daecc838fbb9) in Android?

Comment: I really appreciate it if you could help me out

Comment: the RecyclerView is inside the fragment class of this activity

Comment: Sure i have made an edit. It would solve it now

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still confused , but what I'm saying is `RecyclerView` is inside the fragment not the `viewpager` , the `viewpager` is in the activity that I shown above I mean `MizActivity`

Comment: Here is the code form my **[fragment](https://pastebin.com/hq9p6MEL)**

Comment: viewpager is in the activity that I shown above I mean `TvShowEpisodeDetails`

Comment: here is the **[viewpager adapter](https://pastebin.com/5VRdRCQC)** which is inside `TvShowEpisodeDetails`

Comment: the `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);` where do you mean I should move it ?, because it is already inside  the `onClick` Method

Comment: Hi cyberpunk, now that I saw the source code I have a better understanding. It seems like you lack the implementation of Listener Pattern in Android. You need to apply this in order to achieve your desired behavior. Please checkout out this article and apply it in your app. https://medium.com/android-gate/recyclerview-item-click-listener-the-right-way-daecc838fbb9

Comment: Ok I will do it right away , please help me out if I'm stuck

Comment: Sure, feel free to ask me :)

Comment: I'm trying to apply it to my code , but the problem is , the example code uses kotlin , which I know nothing about , I don't know about this `fun` thing , please forgive me for that

Comment: Sure, if you are not comfortable with kotlin, there is a java version too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969278/recyclerview-item-click-listener-the-right-way

Comment: Thank you , I will use that

Comment: I recreated the adapter class from scratch **[here it is](https://pastebin.com/5Kh1veTp)**  now I some help need to apply `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position); ` because viewpager is not initialized inside the fragment

Comment: here is a **[video of my app](https://youtu.be/VkMa031JkRc)** , when I click an item from the scrollbar it force closes the view

Comment: When I run it, I get **[NullPointerException](https://pastebin.com/Kz8xMv5b)**  at `listener.onItemClick(item);`

Comment: `listener` is null but `item` returns values  here is breakpoint at **[listener.onItemClick(item)](https://imgur.com/G50KJVT)**

Comment: I appreciate some help, I'm really stuck

Comment: My problem is not solved but I will accept your answer , thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry @cyberpunk I was a little busy with something else. It seems like you have done an excellent job with implementing Adapter Class. However, you are encountering NullPointerException because your adapter is declared as `Static` Member. Adapters should never be static as it could cause a alot of exceptions. Thanks

Comment: line 10 of `PlanetAdapter ` --> `static OnItemClickListener listener;`

Comment: Thank you so much , no problem, I removed the static but I get `Non-static field can not be declared from a static contest`

Comment: I just realized that PlanetAdapter class is declared as static; `public static class PlanetAdapter`. You should NEVER declare an adapter class as static. In addition, using static is a really bad pattern in Android Development, which causes all kinds of lifecycle error because static classes are not aware of Android's lifecycle. Please remove all static properties in adapter. Thanks

Comment: Can you please help me with implementing  `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);`

Comment: I created a new jave file for **[PlanetAdapter](https://pastebin.com/BBYhVpsp)** named `PlanetAdapter.java` in order to get rid of the all static declarations, but I still get null from `listener` and **[NullPointerException](https://pastebin.com/v3H8qY7N)** here is the **[fragment](https://pastebin.com/qEEHWcKL)**

Comment: I also made `OnItemClickListener listener;` public on both ends  I still get **[NullPointerException](https://pastebin.com/yGpVXhzX)**

Comment: I got rid of the NullPointerException from the `listener` now  `listener` returnes value , now all I need is implement `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);` here is [TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment](https://pastebin.com/VvGgcTit) , here is [PlanetAdapter](https://pastebin.com/aRwdeY4J)

Comment: Hey @cyberpunk, you did a great job on eliminating Static elements and solving Nullpointer on `listener`. I just saw your code and things look very nice now. On line 37 of TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment, I already see that you have correctly placed `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);`. Was this source code changed after you have commented?

Comment: Yes , I did some editing after that , I created an interface inside [TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment](https://pastebin.com/1TAnzjN0) to transfer **onClick**  to [TvShowEpisodeDetails](https://pastebin.com/gdQYzGjc) , here is [PlanetAdapter](https://pastebin.com/jEpR5xYc) and I got exactly what I needed , thank you for putting me on the right path, I'm forever grateful.

Comment: "I created an interface inside TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment to transfer onClick to TvShowEpisodeDetails" <-- This was what I needed! Nice! Yes, `interface` will be your friend when dealing with adapters. I am genuinely glad that you were able to do it! Thanks.

Comment: thank you so much , you are the who put me on the right path.