# How to Pass a value from recyclerview adapter to its corresponding Activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm having a RecyclerView. when an item is clicked, those values will be displayed in a dialog box. So now I want those values to be passed to it's activity. Below is my code.

```
Below is my adapter class. Here I have a variable called (availstockTv). I need this variable to be passed to my activity class. 

Adapter class: 
package com.shopping.grocery_ekart.Adapters;

public class AdapterProductUser extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterProductUser.HolderProductUser> implements Filterable {

    private Context context;
    public ArrayList<ModelProduct> productsList, filterList;
    private FilterProductUser filter;
    public AdapterProductUser(Context context, ArrayList<ModelProduct> productsList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.productsList = productsList;
        this.filterList = productsList;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HolderProductUser onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.user_todaydeal, parent, false);
        return new HolderProductUser(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderProductUser holder, int position) {
        ModelProduct modelProduct = productsList.get(position);
        
        String productTitle = modelProduct.getProductTitle();
        String productQuantity = modelProduct.getProductQuantity();       
        String notinStock = modelProduct.getNotinStock();
        String stockValue = modelProduct.getStockValue();

        holder.titleTv.setText(productTitle);
        
        if (notinStock.equals("true")) {            
            holder.stockTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {            
            holder.stockTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
            holder.addToCartTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (notinStock.equals("true")) {                        
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Product out of stock, can't add to cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {                        
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Please select Quantity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        showQuantityDialog(modelProduct);
                    }
                }
            });
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                if (notinStock.equals("true")) {                  
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Product out of stock", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {                    
                    showQuantityDialog(modelProduct);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private double cost;
    private int finalCost;
    private int quantity = 0;
    public int availability;
    private void showQuantityDialog(ModelProduct modelProduct) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_quantity, null);

        TextView titleTv = view.findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
        TextView pQuantityTv = view.findViewById(R.id.pQuantityTv);
       
        ImageButton decrementBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.decrementBtn);
        TextView quantityTv = view.findViewById(R.id.quantityTv);
        ImageButton incrementBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.incrementBtn);
        Button continueBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.continueBtn);
        
        TextView availstockTv = view.findViewById(R.id.availstockTv);

        String title = modelProduct.getProductTitle();
        
        String productQuantity = modelProduct.getProductQuantity();
        
        String availableStock = modelProduct.getProductStock();
        final String price;
       
        cost = Double.parseDouble(price.replaceAll("₹", ""));
        finalCost = Integer.parseInt(price.replaceAll("₹", ""));
        quantity = 1;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setView(view);
        try{
            Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.cart).into(productIv);
        }catch (Exception e){
            productIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.cart);
        }
        titleTv.setText(""+title);
        pQuantityTv.setText(""+productQuantity);
        
        availstockTv.setText(availableStock);
        quantityTv.setText(""+quantity);
       
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

continueBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String title = titleTv.getText().toString().trim();
                
                String quantity = quantityTv.getText().toString().trim();
                //addToCart(productId, title, priceEach, totalPrice, quantity);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

   
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productsList.size();
    }
    
    class HolderProductUser extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private ImageView productIconIv;
        private TextView discountedNoteTv, brandTv, addToCartTv,
                        discountedPriceTv, originalPriceTv, stockTv, dealTv;
        public TextView titleTv;
        private RelativeLayout Rl1;

        public HolderProductUser(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            productIconIv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productIconIv);
            discountedNoteTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.discountedNoteTv);
            titleTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
            brandTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.brandTv);
            addToCartTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addToCartTv);
            discountedPriceTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.discountedPriceTv);
            originalPriceTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.originalPriceTv);
            stockTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stockTv);
            dealTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dealTv);
            Rl1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Rl1);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity class:

```
package com.shopping.grocery_ekart.Activities;

public class ShopDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String cod = "Cash on Delivery";
    private static final String op = "Online Payment";
    private ImageView shopIv;
    private TextView TabTodayDealTv, TabAllProductsTv, shopNameTv, phoneTv, emailTv, openCloseTv, deliveryFeeTv, filterTv,
            addressTv, filteredProductsTv, cartCountTv, dummy;
    private ImageButton callBtn, mapBtn, cartBtn, backBtn, filterProductBtn, reviewBtn, filterBtn;
    private EditText searchProductEt;
    private RecyclerView productsRv, todayDealRv;
    private RelativeLayout todayDealRL, productsRl;
    private RatingBar ratingBar;

    private String shopUid;
    private String myLatitude, myLongitude, myPhone;
    private String shopName, shopEmail, shopPhone, shopAddress, shopLatitude, shopLongitude;
    public String deliveryFee;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    
    private ArrayList<ModelProduct> productsList;
    private AdapterProductUser adapterProductUser;

    private ArrayList<ModelCartItem> cartItemList;
    private AdapterCartItem adapterCartItem;

    private ArrayList<ModelProduct> productList;
    private AdapterProductAdmin adapterProductAdmin;

    private EasyDB easyDB;

    private SharedPreferences sp;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor;
    private Dialog dialog1, dialog2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop_details);

        shopIv = findViewById(R.id.shopIv);
        shopNameTv = findViewById(R.id.shopNameTv);
        phoneTv = findViewById(R.id.phoneTv);
        emailTv = findViewById(R.id.emailTv);
        openCloseTv = findViewById(R.id.openCloseTv);
        deliveryFeeTv = findViewById(R.id.deliveryFeeTv);
        addressTv = findViewById(R.id.addressTv);
        filteredProductsTv = findViewById(R.id.filteredProductsTv);
        callBtn = findViewById(R.id.callBtn);
        mapBtn = findViewById(R.id.mapBtn);
        cartBtn = findViewById(R.id.cartBtn);
        backBtn = findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
        filterProductBtn = findViewById(R.id.filterProductBtn);
        searchProductEt = findViewById(R.id.searchProductEt);
        productsRv = findViewById(R.id.productsRv);
        cartCountTv = findViewById(R.id.cartCountTv);
        reviewBtn = findViewById(R.id.reviewBtn);
        filterBtn = findViewById(R.id.filterBtn);
        filterTv = findViewById(R.id.filterTv);
        ratingBar = findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        dummy = findViewById(R.id.dummy);

        productsRl = findViewById(R.id.productsRl);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        shopUid = getIntent().getStringExtra("shopUid");
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        GridLayoutManager layoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
        productsRv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
easyDB = EasyDB.init(this, "ITEMS_DB")
                .setTableName("ITEMS_TABLE")
                .addColumn(new Column("Item_Id", new String[]{"text", "unique"}))
                .addColumn(new Column("Item_PID", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                .addColumn(new Column("Item_Name", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                .addColumn(new Column("Item_Price_Each", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                .addColumn(new Column("Item_Price", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                .addColumn(new Column("Item_Quantity", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                .doneTableColumn();

        cartCount();
        filterBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        filterTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        dialog1 = new Dialog(this);
        dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.checkout_warning_dialog);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            dialog1.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_dialog));
        }
        dialog1.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog1.setCancelable(false); //Optional
        dialog1.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation; //Setting the animations to dialog

        Button continue_shop = dialog1.findViewById(R.id.continue_shop);

        continue_shop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog1.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog2 = new Dialog(this);
        dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.paymentmode_dialog);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            dialog2.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_dialog));
        }

        dialog2.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog2.setCancelable(false); //Optional
        dialog2.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation; //Setting the animations to dialog

        backBtn = dialog2.findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
        Button clear = dialog2.findViewById(R.id.clear);
        Button pay_now = dialog2.findViewById(R.id.pay_now);
        Button place_order = dialog2.findViewById(R.id.place_order);
        RadioGroup radioGroup = dialog2.findViewById(R.id.groupradio);
        RadioButton radia_id1 = dialog2.findViewById(R.id.radia_id1);
        RadioButton radia_id2 = dialog2.findViewById(R.id.radia_id2);
        TextView status = dialog2.findViewById(R.id.status);

        radioGroup.clearCheck();

        backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                radioGroup.clearCheck();
                pay_now.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                place_order.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                dialog2.dismiss();
            }
        });
        pay_now.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        place_order.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
                    {
                        RadioButton radia_id2 = dialog2.findViewById(R.id.radia_id2);
                        RadioButton radia_id1 = dialog2.findViewById(R.id.radia_id1);
                        if (radia_id1.isChecked()) {
                            pay_now.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            place_order.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            status.setText(op);
                            dummy.setText(op);
                        }
                        if (radia_id2.isChecked()) {
                            place_order.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            pay_now.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            status.setText(cod);
                            dummy.setText(cod);
                        }
                    }
                });
        pay_now.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            { 
                int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                if (selectedId == -1) {
                    Toast.makeText(ShopDetailsActivity.this, "Please select any one option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    RadioButton radia_id2 = (RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(selectedId);
                    submitOrder();
                }
            }
        });
        place_order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                if (selectedId == -1) {
                    Toast.makeText(ShopDetailsActivity.this, "Please select any one option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    RadioButton radia_id1 = (RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(selectedId);
                    submitOrder();
                    deleteCartData();
                }
            }
        });
        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                if (selectedId != -1) {
                    radioGroup.clearCheck();
                    pay_now.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    place_order.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(ShopDetailsActivity.this, "No option is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }  
    private void deleteCartData() {

        easyDB.deleteAllDataFromTable(); //delete all records from cart


    }

    public void cartCount() {
        //keep it public so we can access in adapter
        //get cart count
        int count = easyDB.getAllData().getCount();
        if (count <= 0) {
            //no item in cart, hide cart count textview
            cartCountTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            //have items in cart, show cart count textview and set count
            cartCountTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cartCountTv.setText("" + count); //concatenate with string bcz we cant set integer in text view
        }
    }
        checkOutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (allTotalPrice<1) {
                    dialog1.show();
                }
                else {
                    dialog2.show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public String quantity, name;
    private void submitOrder() {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Placing order...");
        progressDialog.show();
        final String timestamp = "" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        String cost = allTotalPriceTv.getText().toString().trim().replace("₹", "");// remove ₹ if contains
        String paystatus = dummy.getText().toString();
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("orderId", ""+timestamp);
        hashMap.put("orderTime", ""+timestamp);
        hashMap.put("orderStatus", "In Progress"); //In Progress/Completed/Cancelled
        hashMap.put("orderCost", ""+cost);
        hashMap.put("orderBy", ""+firebaseAuth.getUid());
        hashMap.put("orderTo", ""+shopUid);
        hashMap.put("latitude", ""+myLatitude);
        hashMap.put("longitude", ""+myLongitude);
        hashMap.put("PaymentMode", ""+paystatus);
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(shopUid).child("Orders");
        ref.child(timestamp).setValue(hashMap)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        //order info added now add order items
                        for (int i = 0; i < cartItemList.size(); i++) {
                            String pId = cartItemList.get(i).getpId();
                            String id = cartItemList.get(i).getId();
                            String cost = cartItemList.get(i).getCost();
                             name = cartItemList.get(i).getName();
                            String price = cartItemList.get(i).getPrice();
                             quantity = cartItemList.get(i).getQuantity();

                            HashMap<String, String> hashMap1 = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap1.put("pId", pId);
                            hashMap1.put("name", name);
                            hashMap1.put("cost", cost);
                            hashMap1.put("price", price);
                            hashMap1.put("quantity", quantity);

                            ref.child(timestamp).child("Items").child(pId).setValue(hashMap1);



                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(ShopDetailsActivity.this, "Please wait.....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        prepareNotificationMessage(timestamp);

                    }


                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        //failed placing order
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(ShopDetailsActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
    private void loadShopProducts() {
        //init list
        productsList = new ArrayList<>();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.child(shopUid).child("Products")
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //clear list before adding item
                        productsList.clear();
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            ModelProduct modelProduct = ds.getValue(ModelProduct.class);
                            productsList.add(modelProduct);

                        }

                        //setup adapter
                        adapterProductUser = new AdapterProductUser(ShopDetailsActivity.this, productsList);
                        //set adapter
                        productsRv.setAdapter(adapterProductUser);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

    }



    private void prepareNotificationMessage(String orderId) {
        //which user place order , send notification to admin
        //prepare data for notification
        String NOTIFICATION_TOPIC = "/topics/" + category_Constants.FCM_TOPIC;
        String NOTIFICATION_TITLE = "New Order "+ orderId;
        String NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = "Your customer has placed a new order!";
        String NOTIFICATION_TYPE = "NewOrder";

        //prepare json (what and where to send)
        JSONObject notificationJo = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject notificationBodyJo = new JSONObject();
        try {
            //what to send
            notificationBodyJo.put("notificationType", NOTIFICATION_TYPE);
            notificationBodyJo.put("buyerUid", firebaseAuth.getUid());
            notificationBodyJo.put("sellerUid", shopUid);
            notificationBodyJo.put("orderId", orderId);
            notificationBodyJo.put("notificationTitle", NOTIFICATION_TITLE);
            notificationBodyJo.put("notificationMessage", NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);
            //where to send
            notificationJo.put("to", NOTIFICATION_TOPIC);
            notificationJo.put("data", notificationBodyJo);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        sendFcmNotification(notificationJo, orderId);
    }

    private void sendFcmNotification(JSONObject notificationJo, String orderId) {
        //send volley request
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", notificationJo, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                //after sending fcm, start order details activity
                //after placing order open order details page
                Intent intent = new Intent(ShopDetailsActivity.this, OrdersDetailsUsersActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("orderTo", shopUid);
                intent.putExtra("orderId", orderId);


                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //if failed sending fcm, still start order details activity
               // Intent intent = new Intent(ShopDetailsActivity.this, OrdersDetailsUsersActivity.class);
               // intent.putExtra("orderTo", shopUid);
               // intent.putExtra("orderId", orderId);
                //startActivity(intent);
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                //put required headers
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headers.put("Authorization", "key=" + category_Constants.FCM_KEY);

                return headers;
            }
        };
        
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }
}
```

Ho do I achieve this. Badly need help as I'm running out of time for delivery....... Somebody help me. Thanks in Advance:)

Comment: this is a ton of code, but research on how to use callback methods

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **700 (seven hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Code edited. I thought the whole code would give an easy understanding for the question I asked ... @a_local_nobody

Comment: COde edited @AlexMamo sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

1. Activity:

   ```
   public class ShopDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PassingCallback {
           //some code
       }
   ```

Create interface PassingCallback;
Implement method.

2. Edit your adapter:

   ```
   public AdapterProductUser(Context context, ArrayList<ModelProduct> productsList, PassingCallback callback) {
           this.context = context;
           this.productsList = productsList;
           this.filterList = productsList;
           this.callback = callback;}
   ```
3. Add this code to onBindViewHolder:

`holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> listener.sendInfo(<some info, variables>));`

You can see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969278/recyclerview-item-click-listener-the-right-way)

**EDITED:**

Create the interface:

```
public interface PassingCallback {
    void sendInfo(TextView tv); //or whatever you want to send
}
```

Edit in adapter:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
listener.sendInfo(holder.availstockTv));  //add this line, check if the variable is in holder             
                if (notinStock.equals("true")) {                  
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Product out of stock", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {                    
                    showQuantityDialog(modelProduct);
                }
            }
        });
```

[Read the article about callbacks and interfaces](https://www.onespan.com/blog/Callback-Methods-Overview)

Comment: can't understand the onclicklistener code.. can u explain how it works....

Comment: @FrancisRaj which variables you want to pass to Activity?

Comment: availstockTv which is in the  private void showQuantityDialog(ModelProduct modelProduct) function in adapter

Comment: Do I need to create a new class for interface ?

Comment: @FrancisRaj yes. read some articles about callbacks and interfaces