# Android checkbox.isChecked is not working

Tags: java, android, xml, checkbox

#### I am trying to create a like and dislike button. I use Checkboxes to do so.

In the XML code I have two checkboxes one called `like` and the other `dislike`

I'm trying to toggle between the like and dislike buttons. Such that they both cannot be switched on at the same time.

```java
public void onLike(View view) {
        if (dislike.isChecked()) {
            dislike.setChecked(false);
        }
        Toast.makeText(this,"liked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The issue that I am having is that set `setChecked(true)` is not doing anything.

For more context, the XML for the checkbox is defined inside a fragment that has a cardview. Each item in the card view has the checkboxes.

the way I initialized the checkbox in the main activity is as follows: -

```java
View cardViewLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text_row_item,null);
        like = (CheckBox) cardViewLayout.findViewById(R.id.like);
        dislike = (CheckBox) cardViewLayout.findViewById(R.id.dislike);
```

any ideas what's going on?

Comment: `setChecked(true) is not doing anything.` I dont see that code. Moreover you would not need it.

Comment: `if (dislike.isChecked()) {
            dislike.setChecked(false);` Try: `if (like.isChecked()) {
            dislike.setChecked(false);`

Comment: And ... RadioButton ?

Comment: @blackapps you are correct. Using the RadioButton is ideal for this context. I just did so and it worked. However, I am still having issues with the `setCheck(true)`. I want to do so in the `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I've figured out the solution. Since I am using a recycler view with a custom adapter I need to bind the onClick listener via an interface.

Here is a link to another post that will show the necessary steps to implement click listeners in adapters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49969478/11379938