RecyclerView adapter dont trigger onBindViewHolder
I have a problem, and it's that onBindViewHolder is never being executed. When I debug, it does enter setPostList and sets the posts list with the 15 items it should, the issue is that onBindViewHolder is never reached, and I don't know why it might be.
This is my adapter
class PostAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<PostViewHolder>(){

    var posts = mutableListOf<PostModel>()

    fun setPostList(postResponseList: List<PostModel>){
        Log.i("PostAdapter", "setPostList")
        this.posts.clear()
        this.posts.addAll(postResponseList.toMutableList())
        this.notifyDataSetChanged()
        //imprimir la lista de post con un forEach
        posts.forEach { post -> Log.i("PostAdapter", post.toString()) }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = PostItemBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)

        return PostViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostViewHolder, position: Int) {
        try {

        Log.i("PostAdapter", "onBindViewHolder")
        val post = posts[position]
        holder.binding.petNameLabel.text = post.pet.name
        //imprimir el nombre del pet
        Log.i("PostAdapter", post.pet.name)

        holder.binding.aboutLabel.text = post.pet.about
        //imprimir el about del pet
        Log.i("PostAdapter", post.pet.about)

//        holder.binding.animalLabel.text = post.pet.animalType.name
//        //imprimir el tipo de animal
//        Log.i("PostAdapter", post.pet.animalType.name)
//
//        holder.binding.addresLabel.text = post.pet.address
//        //imprimir la dirección
//        Log.i("PostAdapter", post.pet.address)
//
//        holder.binding.breedLabel.text = post.pet.animalType.breed.name
//        //imprimir la raza
//        Log.i("PostAdapter", post.pet.animalType.breed.name)
//
//        holder.binding.ageLabel.text = post.pet.age.toString()
//        //imprimir la edad
//        Log.i("PostAdapter", post.pet.age.toString())
        
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.i("PostAdapter", "Error en onBindViewHolder: ${e.message}")
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return posts.size
    }

    companion object {
        const val POST_ID = "post_id"
    }
}

class PostViewHolder (
    val binding: PostItemBinding
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

I tried putting the notifyDataSetChanged() outside of the adapter and calling it in the fragment where I load the Recycle view but it didn’t work. I also commented out the rest of the labels to test only with the name and the about to see if it was an issue of rendering of the recycleview but it wasn’t so.

How are you setting / using the adapter?

Have you set layoutManager?

This for example is the code used in my app
    /**
 * <h1>Game2RecyclerViewAdapter1</h1>
 *
 * **Game2RecyclerViewAdapter1** adapter for game2
 *
 * Refer to [androidauthority](https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-build-an-image-gallery-app-718976/)
 * by [Adam Sinicki](https://www.androidauthority.com/author/adamsinicki/)
 *
 * @version     5.0, 01/04/2024
 * @see RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
 */
class Game2RecyclerViewAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val galleryList: ArrayList<Game1ArrayList>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Game2RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    var sharedPref: SharedPreferences
    var preference_PrintPermissions: String?

    /**
     * used for TTS
     */
    var tTS1: TextToSpeech? = null

    /**
     * Game2RecyclerViewAdapter1 constructor.
     * set game2 list and context annotation, get print permissions
     *
     */
    init {
        // if is print permitted then preference_PrintPermissions = Y
        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
            context.getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        )
        preference_PrintPermissions = sharedPref.getString(
            context.getString(R.string.preference_print_permissions),
            "DEFAULT"
        )
    }

    /**
     * Called when RecyclerView needs a new RecyclerView.ViewHolder of the given type to represent an item.
     *
     * @param viewGroup viewGroup into which the new View will be added after it is bound to an adapter position
     * @param i int with the view type of the new View.
     * @return RecyclerView.ViewHolder new View created inflating it from an XML layout file
     * @see RecyclerView.Adapter.onCreateViewHolder
     */
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_game_2_cell_layout_1, viewGroup, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    /**
     * Called by RecyclerView to display the data at the specified position.
     * set on click listeners
     *
     *
     * Refer to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969278/recyclerview-item-click-listener-the-right-way)
     * answer of [Reaz Murshed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3145960/reaz-murshed)
     *
     * @param viewHolder RecyclerView.ViewHolder ViewHolder which should be updated to represent the contents of the item at the given position in the data set
     * @param i int with the position of the item within the adapter's data set.
     * @see RecyclerView.Adapter.onBindViewHolder
     *
     * @see addImage
     *
     */
    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, i: Int) {
        viewHolder.title.text = galleryList[i].image_title
        viewHolder.img.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP
        viewHolder.img.contentDescription = galleryList[i].image_title
        //
        addImage(
            galleryList[i].urlType,
            galleryList[i].url, viewHolder.img,
            200,200
        )
        //
        viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener {
            // TTS
            tTS1 = TextToSpeech(context) { status ->
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    tTS1!!.speak(
                        galleryList[i].image_title,
                        TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,
                        null,
                        "prova tts"
                    )
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
            //
            if (preference_PrintPermissions == "Y") {
                printImage(context, galleryList[i].urlType, galleryList[i].url, 200, 200 )
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * returns number of item within the adapter's data set.
     *
     * @return int with number of item within the adapter's data set
     * @see RecyclerView.Adapter.getItemCount
     */
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return galleryList.size
    }

    /**
     * viewholder for game2 recyclerview.
     *
     *
     * @see RecyclerView.ViewHolder
     */
    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val title: TextView
        val img: ImageView

        init {
            //
            title = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.title) as TextView
            img = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.img1) as ImageView
        }
    }

}

