In RecyclerView, why I got -1 when I want to get the position of item being clicked?
I write the click in the adapter.(This adapter deal with an image and a text.)
class  FruitAdapter (val fruitList:List<Fruit>)://Fruit is a data class for an image with its text
    RecyclerView.Adapter<FruitAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    //not very important here I guess   
    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val fruitImage: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.fruitImage)
        val fruitName: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.fruitName)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.fruit_item, parent, false)
        val viewholder=ViewHolder(view)    
        viewholder.fruitImage.setOnClickListener{
            //here I try to get the position
            val position=viewholder.absoluteAdapterPosition 
            Log.e("a",position.toString())}

...
}

and it just output -1 to me in logcat, why??
I try to change the ".absoluteAdapterPosition" to ".bindingAdapterPosition" or ".layoutPosition", but they all -1.

In my opinion, you need to activate onclick listener in the onBindViewHolder function.
See also (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969278/recyclerview-item-click-listener-the-right-way)

onCreateViewHolder is used to create a new ViewHolder that holds a View of the given view type. So if you access position at this point, it returns RecyclerView.NO_POSITION which is -1 because the view you inflated hasn't been bound yet.
Item binding happens in onBindViewHolder.
Solution
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val fruit = fruitList[position]
    holder.fruitImage.setOnClickListener {
        val fruitPosition = holder.adapterPosition
    }
}

For the best practice, you can use ViewBinding.
class FruitAdapter(private val fruitList: List<Fruit>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FruitAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
        
    override fun getItemCount() = fruitList.size
    
    inner class ViewHolder(val binding: FruitItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = FruitItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val fruit = fruitList[position]
        holder.binding.apply {
            fruitName.text = fruit.name
            fruitImage.setOnClickListener {
                val fruitPosition = holder.adapterPosition
            }
        }
    }
    
}


I found one thing, I just change the "return" in the onCreateBiewHolder() from" return ViewHolder(view)"to "return viewholder"(which is the viewholder I created before), the problem was solved. I am not sure why, but anyway it works
